What's the problems in my custom layernorm function?
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

def layer_norm(x, weight, bias, eps=1e-6):
    # x shape: [bs, h, w, c]
    # Calculate mean and variance across the spatial dimensions (height, width)
    mean = np.mean(x, axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True)  # shape: (batch_size, 1, 1, channels)
    var = np.var(x, axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True, ddof=0)  # Use ddof=0 for biased variance

    # Normalize
    x_normalized = (x - mean) / np.sqrt(var + eps)

    # Applying weight and bias
    out = weight[None, None, None, :] * x_normalized + bias[None, None, None, :]
    return out

def test1(x):
    x = np.transpose(x, (0, 2, 3, 1))  # Transpose to [bs, h, w, c]
    weight = np.ones(channels)
    bias = np.zeros(channels)

    normalized_output = layer_norm(x, weight, bias)
    return normalized_output

def test2(x):
    global channels
    x = np.transpose(x, (0, 2, 3, 1))  # Transpose to [bs, h, w, c]
    x_tensor = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32)
    weight = torch.ones(channels)
    bias = torch.zeros(channels)

    # Use PyTorch's layer norm, normalizing over the last dimension (channels)
    normalized_output = F.layer_norm(x_tensor, normalized_shape=(channels,), weight=weight, bias=bias)
    return normalized_output.detach().numpy()

# Testing
batch, channels, height, width = 4, 3, 8, 8
# Generate random input
x = np.random.randint(-10, 10, (batch, channels, height, width))

# Calculate outputs from both implementations
layernorm1 = test1(x)
layernorm2 = test2(x)

# Check if outputs are close
are_close = np.allclose(layernorm1, layernorm2, atol=1e-4)
print("Outputs are close:", are_close)  # Should output True if they are close enough


var = np.var(x, axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True, ddof=0)  # Use ddof=0 for biased variance
var = np.var(x, axis=(1, 2), keepdims=True)

My expectation is are_close==True,, which means layernorm1 and layernom2 have a very small distance. since the layernorm1 and layernorm2 have a large shape, I would display the partial result of layernorm1 and layernorm2. layernorm1[0,0,0:3,0:4] array([[ 0.35208505, 1.06448374, -0.52827179], [-1.6216472 , -1.7376534 , -1.07653225], [-1.12821414, 0.88935017, 1.84752351]]) layernorm2[0,0,0:3,0:4] array([[ 0.07412489, 1.1859984 , -1.2601235 ], [-1.0690411 , -0.2672601 , 1.336302 ], [-1.3920445 , 0.4800153 , 0.9120291 ]], dtype=float32)
I've tryed the variacne method with or without ddof=0, got all False in the print statement.
I wanna know how to implment a custom layernorm simliar to Pytorch's built-in layernorm function.
what layernorm step from the code perspective ?
what does layernorm do to a feature map abount computer vision ?

You are computing the mean/var values along the wrong dimensions.
Pytorch's layer norm computes mean/var values along the dimensions specified by normalized_shape. From the documentation, the input dimensions are expected to be (*, normalized_shape[0], normalized_shape[1], ...).
Your code has normalized_shape=(channels,) with an input permuted to have channels as the last dimension, so you should be computing mean/var along that dimension. Instead you compute it along dims (1, 2).
This is the correct implementation:
def layer_norm(x, weight, bias, eps=1e-5):
    # x shape: [bs, h, w, c]
    # Calculate mean and variance across the spatial dimensions (height, width)
    mean = np.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)  # shape: (batch_size, 1, 1, channels)
    var = np.var(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True, ddof=0)  # Use ddof=0 for biased variance

    # Normalize
    x_normalized = (x - mean) / np.sqrt(var + eps)

    # Applying weight and bias
    out = weight[None, None, None, :] * x_normalized + bias[None, None, None, :]
    return out

Note that I also set eps=1e-5 which is the pytorch default.
With this, running:
batch, channels, height, width = 4, 3, 8, 8
# Generate random input
x = np.random.randint(-10, 10, (batch, channels, height, width))

# Calculate outputs from both implementations
layernorm1 = test1(x)
layernorm2 = test2(x)

# Check if outputs are close
are_close = np.allclose(layernorm1, layernorm2, atol=1e-6)

Results in are_close == True
